# Amadeus flight booking working but Hotel Booking API doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, amadeus

So I first integrated Amadeus for flight booking and everything went well but problem arrived when I started integrating hotel booking. If I use nodejs library of Amadeus, I get a response that my access token is invalid. This is my code of nestjs service and response.

```
async hotelSearch(data) {
  try {
  
    var amadeus = new Amadeus({
      clientId: process.env.API_KEY,
      clientSecret: process.env.API_SECRET
    });
    return await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get(data)

  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

And this is the response.result -

```
"result": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "code": 38190,
                    "title": "Invalid access token",
                    "detail": "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid",
                    "status": 401
                }
            ]
        },
        "parsed": true
    },
    "description": [
        {
            "code": 38190,
            "title": "Invalid access token",
            "detail": "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid",
            "status": 401
        }
    ],
    "code": "AuthenticationError"
}
```

How can I get Invalid Access Token error when I am using the library for it?? Anyway, after facing this issue I decided to use axios instead but still got no success.

```
async getToken(): Promise<{access_token: string}> {
      try {


        const data = qs.stringify({
          client_id: process.env.API_KEY,
          client_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
          grant_type: 'client_credentials' 
        });
        
        const config:AxiosRequestConfig = {
          method: 'post',
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          data: data
        };
        
        return await axios(config)
          .then((response) => {
            return((response.data));
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    }

  
    async hotelSearch(data) {
      try {
        const tokenData=await this.getToken()
        const refreshToken='Bearer '+ ( tokenData).access_token
        console.log('token', refreshToken)
        const config:AxiosRequestConfig = {
          method: 'get',
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          url: 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-city',
          data: data,
          headers: {'Authorization':refreshToken},
          
        };
        return await axios(config).then((response) => {
          return(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return(error);
        });
      
        // var amadeus = new Amadeus({
        //   clientId: process.env.API_KEY,
        //   clientSecret: process.env.API_SECRET
        // });
        // return await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get(data)

      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    }
```

And this is the response I got this time.

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
    "name": "Error",
    "stack": "Error: Request failed with status code 400\n    at createError (E:\\travel-portal\\travel-portal\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\createError.js:16:15)\n    at settle (E:\\travel-portal\\travel-portal\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\settle.js:17:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (E:\\travel-portal\\travel-portal\\node_modules\\axios\\lib\\adapters\\http.js:322:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": null,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Authorization": "Bearer CMHEjXBrpzE7YxF9O7GKygCtzCxO",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.26.1",
            "Content-Length": 117
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-city",
        "data": "{\"cityCode\":\"DEL\",\"radius\":\"5\",\"radiusUnit\":\"KM\",\"checkInDate\":\"2023-03-10\",\"checkOutDate\":\"2023-03-11\",\"adults\":\"2\"}"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I have cross-checked the payload. The bearer token is all good when I console it and even I checked the request with fiddler and there too header and data are getting passed. Any help to get this work through either of the method is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get()` endpoint has been decommissioned so you won't be able to use it. Install the latest version of the [Node](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-node/releases/tag/v8.0.0) library and use the new Hotel Search endpoint as below:

```
var Amadeus = require(amadeus);
var amadeus = new Amadeus({
    clientId: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    clientSecret: 'YOUR_API_SECRET'
});

// Get list of available offers in specific hotels by hotel ids
amadeus.shopping.hotelOffersSearch.get({
    hotelIds: 'RTPAR001',
    adults: '2'
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function (response) {
  console.error(response);
});
```

You can also check the [migration guide](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/migration-guides/hotel-search/) for more details and how to use the new [Hotel Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference) version.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. It seems like this method searches hotels by hotelId, but I want to search hotels by city. If it's not possible how can I map the the hotelIds?

Comment: Hello, the Hotel booking engine flow is starting from Hotel List endpoint `amadeus.referenceData.locations.hotels.byCity.get({cityCode: 'PAR'})` if you would like to search by city, to get the list of Hotel and then Hotel Search endpoint to get price.